# Wrong Number of Arguments rails won't pass argument to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to the world of rails and I am tying to create a package tracking app. I want to be able to pass the tracking number of the package to the rails method I created to scrape the carrier's site.

I am getting a wrong number of arguments error and don't understand why.
Any input is appreciated!

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :packages do
    match '/scrape', to: 'packages#scrape', via: :post, on: :collection
  end
  root 'home#index'

  get 'dashboard' => 'packages#index'
  get '/logout' => 'auth0#logout'
  get 'auth/auth0', as: 'authentication'
  get 'auth/auth0/callback' => 'auth0#callback'
  get 'auth/failure' => 'auth0#failure'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**scrape method**

```
def scrape(tracking_num)
    require 'watir'
    url = "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=#{tracking_num}&requester=WT/trackdetails"
    b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
    b.goto(url)
    text = b.p(:class, 'ups-txt_size_double_lg').when_present.text
    flash.now[:notice] = text
 end
```

**button_to**

```
<%= button_to 'Track', scrape_packages_path(tracking_num: package.tracking), class: "btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" %>
```

Comment: Don't use page scraping - its extremely fragile and performs poorly. UPS provides an free of charge Tracking API that provides both JSON and XML. https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US

Comment: Do mention file names when you add snippets, I think it's an action in the controller. If it is, method(action in the controller) doesn't need any arguments. You get it in `params` object.

Comment: have you used these api's before? I created one as per the instructions from the site (generated my key and all) and I am getting a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. But I did set my headers correctly. (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POST request and action are not used like you wrote.
I answer your direct question first: the actions in controller are called without argument. `def scrape(tracking_num)` expects being called with one argument so it raises an error.

Here are the modifications:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :packages do
    # you can use 'post' directly
    post '/scrape', to: 'packages#scrape', on: :collection
  end
end
```

```rb
  # remove the parameters of method and use params[:tracking_num] to get it
  def scrape
    require 'watir'
    url = "https://www.ups.com/track?loc=en_US&tracknum=#{params[:tracking_num]}&requester=WT/trackdetails"
    b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
    b.goto(url)
    text = b.p(:class, 'ups-txt_size_double_lg').when_present.text
    flash.now[:notice] = text
  end
```

```rb
# add { remote: true, method: :post } to the link
<%= link_to 'Track', scrape_packages_path(tracking_num: package.tracking), class: "btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark", method: :post, remote: true %>
```